# When I call generic handler using cross domain by ajax then data is undefined on success of ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

When I call generic handler using cross domain by ajax then data is undefined on success of ajax.

```
    function loadUser() {
        currentUser = null;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://ips.rhinodev1.edge360.dev/EventVelocity/AsyncHandlers/GetCurrentUser.ashx?',
                dataType: 'script',
                crossDomain: true,
                encode: true
            }).done(loadUser_Done).fail(loadUser_Fail);
        }

function loadUser_Done(data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (txtStatus == "success") {
        try { TestWildCard(); } catch (e) { currentUser_UseWildCardDNS = false;    }
        loadDevices();
    }
    else {
        // Redirect To Login
        window.location.href = "Login.aspx";
    }
}
```

When calling `loadUser()` function its call generic handler, and go to `loadUser_Done()` function, in that I have got 'txtStatus' - "success" , but 'data' is undefined.

So, basically I didn't get my response, so how to solve this issue?
Please give answer.

Answer (score 0):

basically you can just declare `success` property in the ajax syntax:

```
function loadUser() {
        currentUser = null;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://ips.rhinodev1.edge360.dev/EventVelocity/AsyncHandlers/GetCurrentUser.ashx?',
                dataType: 'script',
                crossDomain: true,
                encode: true,
                success: loadUser_Done(data, txtStatus, jqXHR)
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        }

function loadUser_Done(data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (txtStatus == "success") {
        try { TestWildCard(); } catch (e) { currentUser_UseWildCardDNS = false;    }
        loadDevices();
    }
    else {
        // Redirect To Login
        window.location.href = "Login.aspx";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have tried this but its also not working, I didn't get response

Comment: $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://ips.rhinodev1.edge360.dev/EventVelocity/AsyncHandlers/SampleHandler.ashx',
            dataType: "script",
            encode: true,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
I used above ajax script, but still get result is undefined

Comment: what is the output of this url? are you getting a script out of this URL?

Comment: output is undefined

Comment: what would be the expected result of your URL?

Comment: Result of data in text/html format, like 'Hello World'. I have also tried to using JSONP, its working,but I have need to pass datatype as script

Comment: do you have any parameter that needed to pass to your server side method?

Comment: No, no need to pass parameter.

Comment: My sample handler is:




`public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

            StringBuilder sbResponse = new StringBuilder();
            sbResponse.Append("currentUser = new Object();");
            sbResponse.AppendFormat("currentUser.UserId = {0};", "1");
            if (sbResponse.Length > 0)
            {
                context.Response.Write(sbResponse.ToString());
            }
        }`